# How to use the iterator interface to get the following

Tags: java, interface, iterator

So I've got legs that represent components of a journey

A journey is defined by a list of legs

```
private List<Leg> journey = new ArrayList<Leg>();
```

and has the constructor:

```
 public Journey(Station startStation, Station endStation, Service service) {
    journey.add(new Leg(startStation, endStation, service));
}
```

and has the follow available method

```
public Iterator<Leg> iterator() {
    return journey.iterator();
}
```

My question is, how would I use the `iterator interface` to get the first leg of the journey?

Comment: Call next() on the iterator returned.

Comment: Why do you want to use the iterator API to do this, anyway? `journey.get(0)` seems simpler for internal use, and for external use, it seems worthwhile to add a similar method for retrieving legs by index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Leg first = journey.iterator().next();
```

If you need other legs then

```
Iterator<Leg> i = journey.iterator();
Leg first = i.next();
Leg second = i.next();
...
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about getting the second leg, etc in the journey using the iterator, would that also be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Although I really don't know why you want to use Iterator Interface, if you really want, you can do this:

```
// suppose you have a journey already
Iterator<Leg> it = journey.iterator();

Leg firstLeg = null;

// just to be safe that your journey is not empty
if (it.hasNext())
    firstLeg=it.next();
```